# Authorization error Skype Bot a day later

Tags: node.js, botframework

The bot works on such a case: the user subscribes to the event, and then the event (event generated in TeamCity) should receive a notification.
The bot works fine within one day. But at night in most cases new events are not sent to the user.
error 401 "Authorization has been denied for this request" is written in the logs when the message is sent to the user (await context.sendActivity(message))

1. When a user subscribes to an event, I save the link to the conversation.

```
const reference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
reference => saving to base as string (used JSON.stringify)
```

2. When I receive an event, I read the link to the conversation from the database and try to send a message.

```
const reference = JSON.parse(reference from base)
await adapter.continueConversation(reference, async (context) => {
    try {
        const reply = await context.sendActivity(message);
        const reference = TurnContext
             .getReplyConversationReference(context.activity, reply);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})
```

3.The link to the dialogue, after sending the message, is again stored in the database

What could go wrong? Why does the code work fine during the day, and after a long time, stop?
If you send any message to the bot from any user, the messages begin to be sent again.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: "botbuilder": "^4.1.5",
    "botbuilder-azure": "^4.1.5",
    "botframework-config": "^4.1.5",

Comment: The botbuilder packages for node.js are currently at 4.2.1 on npmjs. Can you update them and see if this behavior continues?

Comment: Updated, you need a few days to see that the problem is gone.

Comment: I also found that the authorization problem occurs after server restart. Case:
save the link to the conversation => the server
send event from external system => accepts event => can no longer send a message - gives an authorization error => send via Skype any message to bot
 => the bot successfully sends messages to subsequent events

Comment: Is your azure deployed bot set to 'Always On'?